# How to highlight() a lineplot after crosstalk filter

Tags: r, plotly, data-visualization, r-plotly, htmlwidgets

I am making an interactive plotly plot with R using `highlight()` and crosstalk `filter_select()` functions. However, when the argument "`color`" of plotly's lines match `highlight_key()`, it becomes impossible to highlight any light of the filtered data in the plot.

Let's say you pick up the example in "Interactive web-based data visualization with R, plotly, and shiny" by Carson Sievert, in the [Figure 16.10 of the chapter 16.1 "Graphical queries"](https://plotly-r.com/client-side-linking.html)
The example provided by the book works fine, you can highlight an item after filtering data:

```r
library(gapminder)
g <- highlight_key(gapminder, ~country)
continent_filter <- filter_select("filter", "Select a country", g, ~continent)

p <- plot_ly(g) %>%
  group_by(country) %>%
  add_lines(x = ~year, y = ~lifeExp, color = ~continent) %>%
  layout(xaxis = list(title = "")) %>%
  highlight(selected = attrs_selected(showlegend = FALSE))

bscols(continent_filter, p, widths = 12)
```

[image]

However, **when "`color`" argument of `add_lines()` matches `highlight_key()` variable (in this case, `~country`) it is not possible to filter AND highlight the filtered data**

```r
library(gapminder)
g <- highlight_key(gapminder, ~country)
continent_filter <- filter_select("filter", "Select a country", g, ~continent)

p <- plot_ly(g) %>%
  group_by(country) %>%
  # Please mind that in the next line IS NOT "color = ~continent" as in the last example
  add_lines(x = ~year, y = ~lifeExp, color = ~country) %>%
  layout(xaxis = list(title = "")) %>%
  highlight(selected = attrs_selected(showlegend = FALSE))

bscols(continent_filter, p, widths = 12)
```

[image]

Is it possible to highlight items in an interactive plot_ly lineplot (because I've checked in boxplot and it works) when the color argument of plotly's plot matches the highlight_key?
I've also tried with geom_line() + ggplotly() but won't work neither

Comment: I confirmed this is a package bug and shouldn't be happening https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/1540